# How does auxin-inducible degron technology make it possible to observe an immediate phenotype?

Tags: molecular-biology, molecular-genetics

I am having trouble understanding [this paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/33177522/), which says

> Protein knockdown using the auxin-inducible degron (AID) technology is
> useful to study protein function in living cells because it induces
> rapid depletion, which makes it possible to observe an immediate
> phenotype.

How does protein knockdown allow immediate phenotypes to be observed in general, and specifically using AID technology?

Comment: I don't think the sentence is trying to say that protein knockdown allows immediate phenotypes to be observed in general. Rather, _inducible_ knockdown does. What is your understanding of inducible knockdown mechanics (steps taken by researcher and expected effects)?

Comment: My current understanding is that inducible knockdown (in this context) is the use of a ligand (e.g. auxin) to control the speed of proteolysis of a given protein target. I want to understand why this is used and exactly what the purpose is? I am not so much interested in that paper itself, I just want a basic understanding of how the AID2 system works

Comment: In the future you should [edit] your questions rather than reposting substantially duplicate versions of the same question.